# Multiple Set Knapsack Variation

Tags: algorithm, knapsack-problem

I have been trying to find a variation on the knapsack problem that fits my problem, but either I don't understand the definitions on wikipedia well enough (likely) or I am looking in the wrong places.

My problem requires the maximization of value across multiple sets of data. Given 3 sets of data, I want to be able to pick exactly 2 members from each set while maximizing the profit.

Does anyone know of a variation of the knapsack problem that I can look into to do this?

Thank you

Comment: I dont see the similarity to Knapsack, unless you have some more details. *Pick exactly 2 members from each set*, it looks like a brute force approach is appropriate (not to say we cannot find a better algo)

Comment: Sorry, each member still has a weight, so we are maximizing our profit while within keeping our weight below our knapsacks limit. The difference is that we have multiple sets of values and weights instead of just 1 set

Comment: ok, I figured that out. but still, the fact that you *pick exactly 2 members from each set* makes the problem much different (actually easier) than knapsack. The latter's difficulty lies precisely in the fact that you know nothing about the number of individual elements in the solution, making all combinations candidates. Now, if you say *at least 2 elements from each set* that would be a **much** different issue...

Comment: I see, that makes sense. For what i am doing it isnt exactly 2, but it is a predefined number. I have a brute force method that goes through and checks all of the combinations, but for larger data sets it is too slow which is why I began looking into knapsack for this.

Comment: It is slow, indeed, although "theoretically" it has polynomial time complexity. Maybe you can try to accelerate it by sorting the set by weight and doing some DP. :)